# Why doesn't the margin apply on this Button?

Tags: android

I am pro grammatically creating buttons and specifying the height and width of each prior to adding it to a Grid View:

```
Button discountButton = new Button(this, null, 0, R.style.discount_select_button);
discountButton.setText("blah");
discountButton.setWidth(300);
discountButton.setHeight(300);
discountsGrid.addView(discountButton);
```

The button utilises this style, all items defined within the style get applied except for "layout_margin", why could this be?

```
<style name="discount_select_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_light_background_focusable_color</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/discount_selection_button_shape</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">fill_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:autoSizeMinTextSize">1sp</item>
    <item name="android:autoSizeMaxTextSize">25sp</item>
    <item name="android:autoSizeTextType">uniform</item> 
    <item name="android:autoSizeStepGranularity">1sp</item>
</style>
```

When I apply all the above properties programmatically, all applies successfully but not when defined within a style.

The minimum API level I am targeting is 26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes beginning with `layout_` are not actually part of the view, they are part of that view's `LayoutParams` object, and they define the behavior of the *parent*.

If you use that style definition directly in XML, the margins will work, but from Java they will not.

You can create a `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` object and set the `params.topMargin` field to get your desired result.

Comment: What viewgroup are you adding the button to?

Comment: My bad, setting it programmatically does work while still referencing the style in the constructor. But I'd still ideally only want to define this within the style.

Comment: The view group that buttons are being added to is (from docs) java.lang.Object
   ↳ android.view.View
     ↳ android.view.ViewGroup
       ↳ android.widget.GridLayout

Comment: So if I understand correctly? When you specify the style resource in the constructor the LayoutParams object of that view won't get populated based on attributes defined within the style and will have to also be defined pro grammatically?

Comment: Yeah. When you inflate a view from XML, that _view_ and that view's _LayoutParams_ will both be created. When you construct a view in Java, you are only constructing the _view_. Anything that is a part of the LayoutParams will have to be constructed separately.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the elaboration, I glanced over inflation but didn't read much about it thinking it was not needed considering I was able to specify a style resource, obviously I was wrong.